# How to invite the azure guest user for power pages - using the power pages form

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

My goal is to invite the guest users to the azure active directory by using the power pages user interface. I'm trying to achieve this by making Microsoft form & hitting the graph API using power automate but unfortunately, the HTTP action is only available for the premium version. Please suggest any other way to hit the graph API using power pages form values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [invitation resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0) is not supported in any of the non-premium Send an HTTP request type of actions.

As far as I am aware sending the POST request via a Power Automate flow would not be possible without a premium connector.

*Just to double check I tested it with the actions in the screenshot below. All of them gave a resource/object is not supported for this connector type of error.*

Alternatively, you could look into triggering an Azure function from a flow. But that would probably also be a premium license approach.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but is there any other way to hit the graph API in the power pages portal?? using the power pages form values as the API body ??

Comment: Yes, like you mentioned it is possible via a premium connector like the HTTP. I have used that approach before with the invitation resource type: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Automatically-invite-external-user-to-Azure-AD-and-then-add-the/m-p/1507527/highlight/true#M168558

Can't think of any other approaches which wouldn't involve additional cost or premium connectors. For example an Azure function/automation account (with a PowerShell script) would also require a subscription and cost and also a premium connector to trigger it from a flow.